# Github and local development for an open source project

Tags: git, github

We are working on an open source project and going to publish it on Github. Currently we have a repo on our own server which the developers pull/push to.

Considering this, can we have a setup to do our development using our own repo. And then push to the repo on Github as a single commit once the changes ready to be released?

Or what the standard practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a remote which points to GitHub.

```
git remote add github git@github.com:user/project.git
```

Then you could push to that when you want your changes to appear on the GitHub repo.

```
git push github
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Could you please guide me a bit further about it? Lets say I have created an empty repository on github, now how could I get into the `remote` cycle while keep working my local repo. I really appreciate your help in this regard. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Make your code upto date with the code on your server. Then create a repository on Github and you will get a url for your repository. Then follow these steps

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
git push -u origin --all
```

It will push all your commits and all your branches on your machine to github.
Refer this [git hub link](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository)